# How to create a list of tuples from column Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a "Path" column of my dataframe like this:

```
PATH
[10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.6, 10.0.1.1, 10.0.11.100]
[10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.26, 10.0.14.100]
[10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.26, 10.0.1.22, 10.0.1.2, 10.0.12.100]
[10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.26, 10.0.1.22, 10.0.2.6, 10.0.2.1, 10.0.22.100]
[10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.26, 10.0.1.22, 10.0.2.22, 10.0.2.2, 10.0.23.100]
...
```

I wish could create an "Individuals" column like this:

```
INDIVIDUALS
[(10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18), (10.0.1.18,10.0.1.6) ,(10.0.1.6,10.0.1.1), (10.0.1.1, 10.0.11.100)]
[(10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18), (10.0.1.18, 10.0.1.26), (10.0.1.26,10.0.14.100)]
[(10.0.13.100, 10.0.1.18), (10.0.1.18,10.0.1.26), (10.0.1.26,10.0.1.22),(10.0.1.22,10.0.1.2), (10.0.1.2,10.0.12.100)]
...
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question")

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)? Pleas provide a [mcve] including _code_ so that we better understand how to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the apply method.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'PATH':
    [
        ['10.0.13.100', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.6', '10.0.1.1', '10.0.11.100'],
        ['10.0.13.100', '10.0.1.18', '10.0.1.26', '10.0.14.100'],
    ]
})
df['INDIVIDUALS'] = df['PATH'].apply(lambda x: [(p, x[n+1]) for n, p in enumerate(x[:-1])])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @TimothyHelton